# A bug I am facing with JqueryUI draggable/droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would appreciate if someone can help me out,

here's my code :

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/m796a3ud/`
```

What I want to do is drag an image from these list of Images and be able to get a clone that's draggable, and when I put it inside the box it counts how many images are inside, it works good for the most part but when I try to drag the cloned image in and out of the box a couple of times the clone gets cloned it self which is not what I want, I would really appreciate the help!

thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call ui.helper.remove(); on the out event, try this:

```
$(function() {
    // document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    //     console.log($(':hover').hasClass('draggable'))
    // })
    var n = 0;
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({helper: 'clone'});
        
    $( ".wrong" ).draggable();

    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({    
        accept: ".draggable",
        drop: function( event, ui) {
            console.log(ui.draggable)
            
            console.log($(':hover').hasClass('draggable'))
            var new_signature = $(ui.helper).clone().removeClass('draggable');
            new_signature.draggable();
            $(this).append(new_signature);
           
            if($(new_signature).hasClass("ui-draggable") && !$(new_signature).hasClass("dropped")){
          
                 $(new_signature).addClass("dropped draggable")
                n++;
        $(".count").text("There are " + n + " divs inside parent box detail.");
      

            } 
        },
        out: function(event, ui) {

            ui.helper.remove();

            if($(ui.draggable).hasClass("draggable") && $(ui.draggable).hasClass("dropped")) {
                $(ui.draggable).removeClass("dropped")
                console.log(ui.helper)
            }
            if( n > 0) {
                n--
            }
            $(".count").text("There are " + n + " divs inside parent box detail.");
            
        }
        
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help! :)

But I want to be able to drag the clones outside of the droppable div without them disappearing, also the clone still clones itself if you try and drag it around the droppable div

Comment: I got it to work!! I just called ui.helper.remove(); on the drop event instead and that prevent it from duplicating, thanks for your help!